# Including related data using Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have an existing database that I have used as a context for a project using Entity Framework in a multiple context project. The database contains several classes:

- Market Message   [Base Class]
- MessageType300 [2nd level]
- Meter [3rd level]
- RegisterLevelInformation [4th level]

Using the code first from existing database tools it has created the following:

```
[Table("MarketMessage")]
public partial class MarketMessage
{
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public MarketMessage()
        {
            messageType300 = new HashSet<messageType300>();
            messageType300S = new HashSet<messageType300S>();
            messageType300W = new HashSet<messageType300W>();
            messageType305 = new HashSet<messageType305>();
        }

        public int MarketMessageID { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(4)]
        public string messageType { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(8)]
        public string VersionNumber { get; set; }

        public DateTime MarketTimestamp { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(35)]
        public string TxRefNbr { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(3)]
        public string Sender { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(3)]
        public string Recipient { get; set; }

        [StringLength(10)]
        public string alertFlag { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string fileName { get; set; }

        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<messageType300> messageType300 { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<messageType300S> messageType300S { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<messageType300W> messageType300W { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<messageType305> messageType305 { get; set; }
}

public partial class messageType300
{
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public messageType300()
        {
            Meter = new HashSet<Meter>();
            UsageFactor = new HashSet<UsageFactor>();
        }

        public int messageType300ID { get; set; }

        public int MarketMessageID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(11)]
        public string MPRN { get; set; }

        [StringLength(35)]
        public string MPBR { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(35)]
        public string NetworkReferenceNumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(3)]
        public string LoadProfileCode { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(4)]
        public string DUoSGroup { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(2)]
        public string MeterPointStatusCode { get; set; }

        public DateTime ReadDate { get; set; }

        public virtual MarketMessage MarketMessage { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Meter> Meter { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<UsageFactor> UsageFactor { get; set; }
}

[Table("Meter")]
public partial class Meter
{
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Meter()
        {
            RegisterLevelInformation = new HashSet<RegisterLevelInformation>();
        }

        public int MeterID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(15)]
        public string MeterCategoryCode { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(9)]
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

        [StringLength(3)]
        public string MeterLocationCode { get; set; }

        public int? MessageType300ID { get; set; }

        public int? MessageType300SID { get; set; }

        public int? MessageType300WID { get; set; }

        public int? MessageType303RID { get; set; }

        public int? MessageType305ID { get; set; }

        public int? MessageType306ID { get; set; }

        public int? MessageType306WID { get; set; }

        public int? MessageType307ID { get; set; }

        public int? MessageType307WID { get; set; }

        public int? MessageType310ID { get; set; }

        public int? MessageType310WID { get; set; }

        public int? MessageType320ID { get; set; }

        public int? MessageType320WID { get; set; }

        public int? MessageType341ID { get; set; }

        public int? MessageType342ID { get; set; }

        public virtual messageType300 messageType300 { get; set; }

        public virtual messageType300S messageType300S { get; set; }

        public virtual messageType300W messageType300W { get; set; }

        public virtual messageType305 messageType305 { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<RegisterLevelInformation> RegisterLevelInformation { get; set; }
}

[Table("RegisterLevelInformation")]
public partial class RegisterLevelInformation
{
        public int RegisterLevelInformationID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(3)]
        public string MeterRegisterSequence { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(10)]
        public string TimeslotCode { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(3)]
        public string UOM_Code { get; set; }

        public decimal MeterMultiplier { get; set; }

        public decimal ReadingValue { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(2)]
        public string ReadReasonCode { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(2)]
        public string ReadTypeCode { get; set; }

        public DateTime? PreviousReadDate { get; set; }

        public decimal Consumption { get; set; }

        public decimal EstimatedConsumption { get; set; }

        [StringLength(4)]
        public string ReadStatusCode { get; set; }

        [StringLength(2)]
        public string RegisterTypeCode { get; set; }

        [StringLength(1)]
        public string PostDecimalDetails { get; set; }

        [StringLength(2)]
        public string PreDecimalDetails { get; set; }

        public int? MeterID { get; set; }

        public int? RemovedMeterRegisterID { get; set; }

        public int? NewMeterRegisterID { get; set; }

        public int? RetainedMeterRegisterID { get; set; }

        public virtual Meter Meter { get; set; }
}
```

How can I call the marketmessage and the related children including messagetype300, meter, and register level information data?

In the original database I am able to join the table together using a SQL query as follows:

```
select 
    MarketTimestamp, TxRefNbr, Sender, Recipient, MPRN, 
    NetworkReferenceNumber, LoadProfileCode, DUoSGroup, 
    MeterPointStatusCode, ReadDate, SerialNumber,
    MeterRegisterSequence, TimeslotCode, UOM_Code, MeterMultiplier, 
    ReadingValue, ReadReasonCode, ReadTypeCode, PreviousReadDate, 
    Consumption, EstimatedConsumption, ReadStatusCode, RegisterTypeCode 
from 
    marketmessage as a
inner join 
    messagetype300 as b on a.MarketMessageID = b.MarketMessageID 
inner join 
    Meter as c on b.messageType300ID = c.MessageType300ID
inner join 
    RegisterLevelInformation as d on c.MeterID = d.MeterID
where 
    DUoSGroup = 'T021'
    and TimeslotCode = 'UNR'
order by 
    MarketTimestamp desc
```

I have attempted to join this in the following way but I am unable to access the properties of either the meters or the register level information from my view:

```
var test = db.MarketMessage.Where(m => m.messageType == "300S")
            .Include(m => m.messageType300S.Select(mt => mt.Meter))
            .ToList();
```

I am attempting the following:

```
<td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Recipient)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.alertFlag)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.fileName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsDeleted)
        </td>
        <td>
        @foreach (var m in item.messageType300S.Select(m => m.Meter).FirstOrDefault())
        {
            @Html.Display(m.SerialNumber)
        }
    </td>
```

Obviously I dont really want to be iterating the meters in this manner although this is not even displaying the serial number despite it being found when I am debugging so lost as to what is going on

Comment: Well you only have one navigation property in your `Include` statement. You have to add those of your 3rd and 4th level as well, see here on how to load data over multiple levels https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx.

Comment: can I apply multiple includes? I thought I could then include the meter on the messagetype

Comment: If you want to load more navigation properties of your `MarketMessage` class you can chain multiple `Include` calls yes. But you want to load properties of related entities, so you have to do something like `Include(mt => mt.messageType300.Select(m => m.Meter))`.

Comment: please see my updated question, I am unable to access meters from the view

Comment: Your code is incomplete, what properties are you trying to access?

Comment: I am trying to access first the details of the meter like serial number etc and then I need to access any of the register level information relating to that meter

Comment: Ok, as long as you only access details of `Meter` you should be fine with your current query. For navigation properties like register level infos you have to load these first, so adjust your query to `Include(mt => mt.messageType300.Select(m => m.Meter.Select(n => n.RegisterLevelInformation)))`.

Comment: how can I then call it from the view though? Do I have to call the selects when iterating the meter details

Comment: Depends on what you want to display ;) according to your model, one of your `MarketMessage` items has X `messageType300s` elements, where each one again has Y `Meter` elements, and so on. So for one row you end up with X*Y possible serial numbers.

Comment: It will have max of two meters

Comment: Ok, anyway you have to figure out how you want things displayed and fix your foreach.

Comment: I have fixed it but I am still unable to access the detail within the serial number although i can see it on debug it is not displaying

Comment: If you can see it in debug then your related data is loaded and your problem is somewhere in MVC code. You should post a separate question about this issue if you can't figure it out.